# Is it possible to include date/time formatting within a Delphi TClientDataSet XML format?

Tags: xml, delphi, datetime, formatting

I am creating a couple of unrelated XML files that will each display in a viewer. The viewer comprises a TClientDataSet, a TDataSource and a TDBGrid and I was hoping to have no field definitions or declarations in code but to read these in using the XML data. I first created my XML files using fields created at runtime in a test application:

```
 ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Date', ftDate);
 ClientDataSet1.FieldDefs.Add('Machine', ftString, 50);
```

etc., and then wrote out the data using:

```
 ClientDataSet1.SaveToFile( 'test.xml', dfXML );
```

From this point on, the XML should be the only field information. The structure of the XML is quite clear and I've been able to edit it to my needs. I am now loading it into my viewer and using the schema in the XML to create the fields. My question involves the display of the ftDate field which here in the UK displays as 01/12/2008. Inspecting the XML output I see that the metadata is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="true"?>
-<DATAPACKET Version="2.0">
-<METADATA>
-<FIELDS>
<FIELD fieldtype="date" attrname="Date"/>
<FIELD fieldtype="string" attrname="Machine" WIDTH="50"/>
```

and a typical date record is:

```
-<ROWDATA>
<ROW Machine="Acer Iconia W510" Date="20130501"/>
```

Ideally I would like to see "May 2013" or at least "01 May 2013" displayed in the DBGrid. It seems this since the TClientDataSet is getting so much info at XML load time, it might be possible to include some other data to control the displayed format. Is this possible? To research this I've looked at many TClientDataSet XML files, particularly the demo XML files grouped under:

```
C:\Users\Public\Documents\RAD Studio\12.0\Samples\Data
```

and while these are very useful for showing the data types, they all seem to use default dates and times. 
Thanks for any pointers.

Comment: No, the XML stores the data and not the kind of presentation. This is/has to be done by the client UI itself

Comment: Thanks. Is there a specification for this data somewhere? For example I see that if I include time information with a date, the ROW field data goes from (say) "20130501" to "20130501T03:56:00000" and I guess this must be defined..

Comment: It is an [ISO8601 format](http://books.xmlschemata.org/relaxng/ch19-77049.html)

Comment: It is also known by delphi [DateToISO8601](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.DateToISO8601) and [ISO8601ToDate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.DateUtils.ISO8601ToDate)

Comment: That's a very useful link to an interesting book, thanks.

Comment: @Brian: The typical way to deal with the display of the date is to set the `DisplayFormat` of the field itself (eg., YourField.DisplayFormat := 'mm/dd/yyyy') in your app. The XML in this case is a data storage medium, and it shouldn't matter what format the data is stored in; the display is a presentation (front-end) issue, and should be handled there.

Comment: Thanks Ken, useful info.